# How to translate this SQL Query to DQL?

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

I have a lot of difficulties in trying to translate this SQL query to a DQL one (I am using Symfony2).

`SELECT d.* FROM Document d JOIN DocumentType dt ON dt.id = d.document_type_id WHERE (d.dateFinal - INTERVAL dt.renewal SECOND) > NOW();"`

Thanks a lot !

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Is my answer any helpful? If it wasn't, you should elaborate on what your difficulties are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instead of database fields, you need to use the fields of you `Document` and `DocumentType` classes.
- The [join](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) is done by naming the [association field](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html) of your document (something like `d.documenttype`)
- For those MySQL date functions: At least as far as I know, you would need to write [custom DQL functions](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html?highlight=interval). Behind that link there is an example of an `INTERVAL` function. This might be the point where you want to execute the native SQL query instead.

```sql
SELECT d 
FROM MyProject\Model\Document d
    JOIN d.documenttype
WHERE [...your own DQL functions here...]
```