# equivilent syntax in DQL: Convert a part of sql query into DQL (Doctrine 1.2)

Tags: sql, doctrine, dql

I am converting a very old query from SQL to DQL, and part of the query looks pretty messed up, but it needs to be done.

```
SELECT......
substr( content, locate( 's:7:\"country\";s:', content ) +19, 
right( substr( content,
locate( 's:7:\"country\";s:', content ) , 17 ) , 1 ) ) AS country_code,
```

Is it possible to convert this to DQL? I do not mean actual conversion tools, but the euquivalent syntax in DQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer this, the sql to dql conversion

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/documentum-users/message/27959

Comment: Thanks, but i am not sure how this is helpful exactly...from what is see it is DQL to SQL conversion (other way around) :)

Comment: @Confidence u may also refer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351563/how-to-translate-this-sql-query-to-dql